# Adding summary statistics (or even raw data points) to dodged position boxplots

Tags: r, algorithm, ggplot2

Say you have the following dataset:

```
trt &lt;- ifelse(runif(100)&lt;0.5,"drug","placebo")
inj.site &lt;- ifelse(runif(100)&lt;0.5,"ankle","wrist")
relief &lt;- 20 + 0.5*(inj.site=="ankle") + 0.5*(trt=="drug") + rnorm(100)
to.analyze &lt;- data.frame(trt,inj.site,relief)
```

Now, the idea is to make a boxplot with injury site on the x-axis and boxes by treatment side-by-side:

```
bplot &lt;- ggplot(to.analyze,aes(inj.site,relief,fill=trt)) + geom_boxplot(position="dodge")
```

Easy enough. But now I want to add raw data points on top of the boxes. If I didn't have boxes with `position="dodge"`, this would be easy:

```
bplot + geom_point(aes(colour=trt))
```

However, this draws points in between the boxes, and adding a `position="dodge"`to this geometry does not seem to work. How do I adjust this so that points are drawn over the boxes?

Bonus: same situation with using `stat_summary(blah,y.fun=mean,shape="+")` to overplot the means, which has the same issue.

Comment: relief <- 20 + 0.5*(inj.site==ankle) + 0.5*(trt=="drug") + rnorm(100)

should be:

relief <- 20 + 0.5*(inj.site=="ankle") + 0.5*(trt=="drug") + rnorm(100)

Comment: I know it's been a long time ago this question was formulated, but still, I am wondering what type of `r` code you have  at  the beginning of your question?

Answer (score 3):

Hadley will doubtless correct me if I'm wrong here...

Here's the natural syntax:

```
bplot + geom_point(aes(colour=trt), position=position_dodge(width=.5))
```

(position="dodge" will do the same thing, without the parameter.)

When I plot it, I get something that looks like a position_jitter(), which is presumably what you get too.

Curious, I went to look in the source, where I found the pos_dodge() function. (Type *pos_dodge* at an R prompt to see it...) Here's the end of it:

```
within(df, {
  xmin <- xmin + width / n * (seq_len(n) - 1) - diff * (n - 1) / (2 * n)
  xmax <- xmin + d_width / n
  x <- (xmin + xmax) / 2
})
```

n is the number of rows of the data frame. So it looks like it's dodging the individual points by a fraction indexed by the row! So the first point is dodged width/n, the second is dodged 2 * width/n, and the last is dodged n * width/n.

This is obviously not what you *meant*, although it is what you *said*. You may be stuck recreating the dodged boxplot manually, or using a different visualization, like faceting maybe?

```
ggplot(to.analyze,aes(inj.site,relief)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ trt)
```

Comment: In faceting, it works perfectly. However, for visualizing reasons I'd much rather have dodged position, though I might try faceting on inj.site?